# How to use Azure Table Service SAS URL generated from the portal?

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I am generating SAS from the Azure portal.
[image: SAS Generation from Azure Portal]

Below is the code, I am using to insert into a table storage.

```
string SAS = "SAS Token from the portal";
StorageCredentials storagecred = new StorageCredentials(SAS);
var ctc = new CloudTableClient(
                new StorageUri(new Uri(
              "https://{myaccountname}.table.core.windows.net")),storagecred);
var table = ctc.GetTableReference("{tablename}");
table.CreateIfNotExists();
```

I am getting a **table access forbidden error (403)**. Am I passing any incorrect parameter? My understanding is that after generating the SAS, account credentials are not required. The IP address provided is my private IP.

Comment: Do take a look at `StorageException` especially `RequestInformation` in there. You should find more details about this 403 error.

Comment: @GauravMantri In the `RequestInformation` I am getting a message- Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.

Comment: You can't put the private IP address there.. You have to use your public IP address. Azure can't see your private IP address.

Comment: @juunas Thanks! The issue was with the IP address, when I used the public one, it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use your public-facing IP address, not the private address as that is not what Azure sees. 10.x.x.x addresses are all private addresses, along with a few other blocks like 192.168.x.x.